# Is it possible to detect muonium at the end of the experimental area of a particle accelerator by exciting its electron?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, particle-accelerators

I've been wondering: if the muonium atom is very similar to the hydrogen atom, can I detect it (at the end of the experimental area in a particle accelerator) by exciting and then unexciting its electron with a very precise laser beam (assuming that we know the values of muonium energy levels by QED)? And would the photons emitted by the laser interfer with the rest of the experience?

Thanks

Comment: "can I detect it (at the end of the experimental area in a particle accelerator)" it is more complicated than this, since the muonium is not stable, the muon has a decay lifetime around microseconds. The experiment needs a specific design. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muonium

Comment: @annav what do you suggest for it? Considering that the experimental setup to obtain muonium is already designed, which method would you suggest to detect this atom?

Comment: the answer by rob gives a method. To know you have muonium you have to detect energy levels. Creation methods are described here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01195.pdf paragraph 3.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this has been done, but the detection method was photoionization rather than photon emission after de-excitation.
From [Past, Present, and Future of Muonium](https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-ex/0404013) by Jungmann, 2004:

> Doppler-free excitation of the 1s-2s transition has been achieved
>   in pioneering experiments at KEK[14]
>   and at RAL[15]. In all these experiments
>   two counter-propagating pulsed laser beams at 244 nm wavelength
>   were
>   employed to excite the n=2 state.  The successful transitions were then
>   detected by photo-ionization with a third photon from the same laser field.
>   The released μ+
>   was then registered on a micro-channel plate detector.

The KEK and RAL citations are

14. [Steven Chu et al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 60 (1988) 101](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.60.101); see also: [K. Danzmann et
    al., Phys. Rev. A 39 (1989) 6072](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.39.6072)
15. [F. Maas et al., Phys. Lett. A 187 (1994) 247](https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(94)90903-2); [W. Schwarz et al., IEEE
    Trans.Instr.Meas. 44 (1995) 505](https://doi.org/10.1109/19.377893); [K. Jungmann et al., Z.Phys
    .D 21 (1991) 241](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01426380)

Comment: If I use an anti-muon beam to obtain muonium (this beam collides into an insulator leaving free electrons that combining with the anti-muons will originate muonium) is this method possible? By photoionizing the atom I would obtain an electron and an anti-muon, right?...

Comment: You sound like you're on the right track ... I've turned the references into links, but I haven't read any of them yet. Not my field. But the successful experiments are described there.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again! Meanwhile I had an idea but I don't know if it is possible or not... When we apply photo-ionization, the electron acquires some momentum. Measuring the momentum of that electrons may help me concluding that muonium was formed, right? And would a magnet at the end of the experimental area do this?